# Writing XML Document by Getting Data from DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

How to **write XML document** with specified nodes by **taking data from DataGridView** ?
I've a DataGridView and need to wirte XML file containing that data which is further loadable in application too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will be having a datasource to the grid, using that datasource itself you can create the xml

Comment: I tried this code: `DataSet dsTargetData = new DataSet();
                    dsTargetData = (DataSet)(dgvBooksDetails.DataSource);
                    dsTargetData.WriteXml(sfdFileData.FileName);` but getting this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: debug and check if dsTargetData is having data after it is assigned from the gridview.datasource. Also try to hardcode the file name like c:\text.xml

Comment: Well, I come to know after debugging; null is in dsTargetData and same error is getting back.

Comment: Then you need to check for null like  "If not dsTargetData is dbnull.value then  dsTargetData.WriteXml(sfdFileData.FileName);

Comment: how you are assigning the datasource to the Grid? can you post the code

Comment: you can refer this link for simple example   [link] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23669/Export-DataSet-to-XML-File)

Comment: `DataSet dsTargetData = new DataSet();                     dsTargetData = (DataSet)(dgvBooksDetails.DataSource);`

Comment: You dont need to convert the gridview datasource to dataset and assign it. Instead before assiging the data source to the gridview, check for the record count, if its greater than zero then you can convert that datasource to dataset and then use dataset.WriteXml(xml_document_object)

Comment: Thanks. It requires to make sure that dataset have table with rows count greater than zero. Then it can be used to write in XML using DataSet.WriteXML(string) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Serialize` the data of the `DataGridView`, look at the `DataSource` of
the `dataGridView`.